# jQuery get data of form that was submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several forms each with class 'cx' and a different id of type 'cx-1', 'cx-2', ...

I want to create a jQuery listener that is activated each time one of them is submitted, so I use:

```
$(".cx")
.submit() {

function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

}

}
```

And to here all is good. I then want to get the form's data to submit it using an ajax request. I use `$.ajax()` but the problem is I don't seem to be able to call `e.serialize()`, I'm told it's not a function. As I have multiple forms with the same class I cannot use `this` either, so I've resorted to  `myData = $("#"+this.id);` which doesn't seem a fantastic solution. Any advice?

Comment: `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: As I've seen various versions on the Internet, could you please clarify over the difference between this, $this and $(this)?

Comment: If you open a function on submit event of form, even if the selector corresponds to a class, using `$(this).serialize` will refer to the element that triggered the action

Comment: `this` == DOM element, `$(this)` == DOM element wrapped in jquery functionally, `$(this)[0] == this`